# Framework7 Single Searchbar for multiple Virtual Lists

Tags: javascript, list, cordova, search, html-framework-7

**The Task**

Picture the typical search-bar and list of results. With framework7 in my Cordova app we can of course implement this easily even with a virtual list where elements aren't all being rendered. But what I'm trying to implement is a search-bar which will effect two virtual lists. The reason for this is as part of the app I'm creating there will be a list for new and refurbished equipment. Each list is on a different slider tab on the same page, so only one list will be seen at any one moment. But I need to use a singular search-bar to filter both.

**What I've done so far**

Currently the slider with two separate virtual lists is set up, the search bar is initiated. Is there any good way to allow the searchbar to apply to both lists without going crazy with the customSearch true parameter. If that is the only option how would I keep the default methods for filtering lists, I simply want to apply it twice.

I've also considered creating a second searchbar with display:none and having it copy input over from the seen searchbar. Then hidden searchbar could apply to one list while the seen one would apply to the other. But that would be really hacky and not neat at all.

Sorry If this is a bit unclear, I'm not sure how best to approach the challenge, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initialise my two virtual lists, I make the search function accessable from outside of that. Then I initalise my searchbar with customSearch true, on search I use my virtual list (vl) array and search them individually using the filter and query functions available. It was a bit of a pain but this works perfectly fine. The vl[1] in this example is just a copy of vl[0] since I haven't actually set it up yet.

```
    function virtualSearchAll(query,items){//search query
        var foundItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            // Check if title contains query string
            if (items[i].internal_descriptn.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase().trim()) >= 0) foundItems.push(i);
        }
        // Return array with indexes of matched items
        return foundItems;
    }

    var vl = [];
    vl[0] = myApp.virtualList('.vl0', {//initialise new products
        items: selectProd,
        template: '<li data-value="{{model_id}}" class="item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title list-title">{{internal_descriptn}}</div></div></li>',
        searchAll: function(query,items) {
            return virtualSearchAll(query, items);
        }
    });
    vl[1] = myApp.virtualList('.vl1', {//initialise test/referb products
        items: [{internal_descriptn:"test desc",model_id:"wehayy"}],
        template: '<li data-value="{{model_id}}" class="item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title list-title">{{internal_descriptn}}</div></div></li>',
        searchAll: function(query,items) {
            return virtualSearchAll(query, items);
        }
    });

    var mySearchbar = myApp.searchbar('.searchbar', {
        customSearch: true,
        searchIn: '.item-title',
        onSearch: function(s) {
            previousQuery = s.query;
            for (let n in vl) {
                let vlItems = virtualSearchAll(s.query,vl[n].items);
                vl[n].filterItems(vlItems);
                if(vlItems.length === 0) {//if the search has no results then show no results element else hide it
                    $('.vl'+n+'-not-found').show();
                } else {
                    $('.vl'+n+'-not-found').hide();
                }
            }
            highlightRows();
        }
    });
```

I should add that highlightRows() is part of a different functionality which needs to be refreshed on every search. You can ignore that